# Is there a way to disable FirebaseMessagingService for the Espresso test?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service

Is there a way to disable `FirebaseMessagingService` for the Espresso test? Or somehow provide other implementation of `FirebaseMessagingService` in Espresso tests. Or enable `FirebaseMessagingService` manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question adequately. Suppose the implementation gives you a problem during the execution of the test. In that case, you can wrap it with an interface and, using dependencies injection, provide a mock implementation inside your UI tests.